# I want only certain buttons to be displayed through jquery

Tags: jquery, button

I have a grid of buttons ehere user onpens up the gird by clicking on the (Open Grid) link and then clicking on a button in that grid. What will then happen is that a set of buttons appear below the text box depending on the button selected from the grid. So if user select button "1" then button "A" appears, if user selects button "2" then buttons "A" and "B" appears and so on.

Now this is done through jquery code below:

```
$(".gridBtns").click(function() {

   var clickedNumber = this.value;

   $('.answerBtns').each(function (index) {
      if (index < clickedNumber)
         $(this).show();
      else
         $(this).hide();
   });

});
```

But wat I want to do is that if user selects button "True or False" from the grid, I want only the buttons "True" and "False" under the text box and if user selects "Yes or No" button from the gird, then I only want buttons "Yes" and "No" to display under the text box, How can this be do in my jquery code?

Also if user selects "True or False" button or "Yes or No" button, then I want the "Number of Answers" text box to disappear and display the span tag "N/A" only, does anyone know to do this in jquery

Thanks and code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSy97/10/)

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone know to do this in jquery code or does it have to be done
>   in javascript using if statements?

This question doesn't have any sense. Since jQuery is a javascript library you can't use jQuery **or** javascript. You must use (you are already doing it) both of them.

About how to do this, you must establish diferent conditions for number buttons and options buttons in the grid (for example with 'if' statement, as you say, or with a diferent class for those options buttons than for the numerical ones).

Comment: Sorry what I meant was did I need to do to it in my jquery or separately outside my jquery function

Comment: Inside if you want it to occur on click event.